# How to call a hidden method from two times inherited base class in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, multiple-inheritance

Consider a class `D` inherited from two classes `B` and `C`, each of which inherits not-virtually class `A`. There is a method `f` in `A`, and the same named method in `B` hiding the method from `A`. I would like to call `A::f()` from `B`-base class of `D` object as follows:

```
struct A { void f() {} };
struct B : A { void f() {} };
struct C : A {};
struct D : B, C {};
int main() { D{}.B::A::f(); }
```

Unfortunately, it works only in MSVC, while both GCC and Clang produce the error:

```
error: 'A' is an ambiguous base of 'D'
```

demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jY3v876hK

It looks like GCC/Clang accept but completely ignore `B::` prefix in `B::A::f()`. Are they right in doing so according to the standard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are they right in doing so according to the standard?

Yes. The nested name specifier in `A::`, `B::A`, or `D::B::A` all serve the same purpose, to name the class `A`.

**[basic.lookup.classref]**

> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lookup.classref#4) If the id-expression in a class member access is a qualified-id of the form
>
> ```
> class-name-or-namespace-name::...
> ```
>
> the `class-name-or-namespace-name` following the `.` or `->` operator is first looked up in the class of the object expression ([class.member.lookup]) and the name, if found, is used. Otherwise it is looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression.

The nested name specifier does not name "a path" to the member, it names a base of `D`. And to name `A` results in ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers show why the compiler is correct.

In order to achieve what you want, you can do:

```
int main() { static_cast<B&&>(D{}).A::f(); }
```

It's a bit ugly, though.

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Mzs8rsdf5