# Why should the access of member of A in inheritance chain D->B,C->A cause ambiguity?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, ambiguity

I tried to compile the following code

```
struct A{
    int a;
};

struct B : A{};

struct C : A{};

struct D: B,C{
    void f(){
        ++B::A::a;
    }
};

int main()
{}
```

The compilation of this code resulted in ambiguity error in both [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/Yf8hah6P6) and [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/4rqK9aYvv). I understand the ambiguity error when instead of `++B::A::a` writing `++a`. But why are we getting this error when accessing `a` explicitly? Where is this behavior defined in standard.

Comment: Not sure exactly why, but `++B::a` works as expected.

Comment: @super, really weird.

Comment: @super Well, yes that [works](https://godbolt.org/z/aoajaWbaj), because, as noted in the dupe's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69003745/4944425), `B::A` is a way to name class `A`, which is inherited both via `B` and `C`, resulting in ambiguity. `B::a` resolves the ambiguity by explicitly naming class `B` and its member.